# Get total occurrences based on exactly 15 number in sequence

Tags: r

I currently have a messy DF where I'd like to scan everything at once for exactly 15 digit sequences. The problem with the code below is that it returns all sequences that are at least 15 digits - so I get the total occurrences returned when they also exceed 15.

Can I return occurrences based on exactly 15 and omit anything less than 15 or greater from the aggregation?

```
sum(str_count(list_all_df2,pattern = "[0-9]{15?}"))
```

Comment: Perhaps `sum(str_count(list_all_df2,pattern = "\\D[0-9]{15}\\D"))`

Comment: If there are no non-digits, you may add `sum(str_count(list_all_df2,pattern = "\\D*[0-9]{15}\\D*"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text extraction is always difficult without a firm example, but we can create a vector of text containing random-length strings of digits like this:

```r
set.seed(12345)

string <- apply(
  replicate(30, sample(c(0:9, " "), 50, TRUE, prob = c(rep(10, 10), 7))),
   2, paste, collapse = "")
  
head(string)
#> [1] "849452168 028055552 51 875863690381144729549310007"
#> [2] " 91386805393 9 3 27 861107 86246002196904907868925"
#> [3] "17 7647433759594 701660889 2390898 4822968372  641"
#> [4] "9691398547874956 295 3915984992533 91 229411 03935"
#> [5] "74268900671853 516722206484567176886 465  4978 619"
#> [6] "2 03440226 9948029 8212 95601429203509668901919360"
```

To get all the length-15 strings of digits from this vector we can do:

```
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(string, "\\b\\d{15}\\b"))
#> [1] "013567419835491" "607222319557192" "742113985775821" "928244409745755"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Am I reading `\\b' as creating a boundary for exactly 15? (between 1 and 15) and \\d any digit? Thank you

Comment: @DreDay yes. It picks out "word" boundaries, even if the "word" is a string of numbers.